# Is there a way to merge split clips on video editing?

Tags: video-sequence-editor

How do I merge two or many split clips together? Is there a way to do that? If so, what shortcut? Thanks

Im using 2.93.3

Answer (score 2):

You can't join clips in the sense of splicing one to the end of the other, because Blender treats strips as atomic objects.

You can place two strips adjacent to each other; set the render length to their total frame range; and then render to a single file, creating a file that contains the spliced strips.

You can group strips into meta groups by selecting the two clips, right clicking and selecting group from the menu.

Comment: The only reason I asked this question was because I wanted a simpler way to speed up clips. If I could merge split clips, I could speed it up as a whole? Do your methods help this problem?

Comment: I don't think they make any difference.  You still have to do the time remapping, and you can already do that on adjacent clips.

Comment: You can collect several strips in a meta strip and add speed effect to that, maybe an Adjustment layer and then add a speed strip to that(will speed up the visual result of the underlying strips).